# Not receiving content headers from Web API to Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, angular-http

I have a Web API that I want to return a file and the file details.

```
HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
result.Content = new StreamContent(file);
result.Headers.Add("filename", "MyFile");
return result;
```

Within Angular I do the following:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.headers());
});
```

The response.headers() does not contain my header record.

What am I missing?

I've looked at other examples online and they are like this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be response.headers('filename') ?

Comment: I've tried that too. I believe response.headers() just returns all the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following line and change the name to x-filename

result.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-filename");